# Table has no column

Tags: android, kotlin, sqlite3

Следовал туториалу для успешного внедрения sqlite в приложение.

Имею следующее:

ServerContract.kt

```
object ServerContract {

    class Entry : BaseColumns {
        companion object {
            val TABLE_NAME = "servers"

            val COLUMN_ID = "id"
            val COLUMN_NAME = "name"
            val COLUMN_IP = "ip"
        }
    }
}
```

Server.kt

```
class Server {
    var id: Int = 0
    var name: String? = null
    var ip: String? = null

    constructor(id: Int, name: String, ip: String) {
        this.id = id
        this.name = name
        this.ip = ip
    }

    constructor(name: String, ip: String) {
        this.name = name
        this.ip = ip
    }
}
```

ServerHelper.kt

```
class ServerHelper(context: Context, factory: SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory?) : SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION) {

    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase) {
        val SERVERS_TABLE = ("CREATE TABLE " + ServerContract.Entry.TABLE_NAME + "(" + ServerContract.Entry.COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + ServerContract.Entry.COLUMN_NAME + "TEXT," + ServerContract.Entry.COLUMN_IP + " TEXT" + ")")

        db.execSQL(SERVERS_TABLE)
    }

    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + ServerContract.Entry.TABLE_NAME)
        onCreate(db)
    }

    fun addServer(server : Server) {
        val values = ContentValues()

        values.put(ServerContract.Entry.COLUMN_NAME, server.name)
        values.put(ServerContract.Entry.COLUMN_IP, server.ip)

        val db: SQLiteDatabase = writableDatabase

        db.insert(ServerContract.Entry.TABLE_NAME, null, values)
        db.close()
    }

    companion object {
        private val DATABASE_VERSION = 1
        private val DATABASE_NAME = "database.db"
    }
}
```

И такое применение всего этого:

```
 val dbHelper = ServerHelper(this, null)
 dbHelper.addServer(Server("1","1"))
```

Но получаю ошибку:

```
10-23 20:39:09.059 4608-4608/mud.duck E/SQLiteLog: (1) table servers has no column named name
10-23 20:39:09.060 4608-4608/mud.duck E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting ip=1 name=1
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table servers has no column named name (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO servers(ip,name) VALUES (?,?)
```

Много чего перепробовал, но не смог починить. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот тут явно пробел отсутствует

```
ServerContract.Entry.COLUMN_NAME + "TEXT,"
```

В результате создается поле `nameTEXT` типа `BLOB`.